# в окрУге или в Округе — ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

Куда падает ударение в словосочетании "в округе не было ни души", на первый или второй слог?

Comment: А Вы имеете в виду **округ** или **округу**? Пока это не выясним, не сможем точно угадать, где здесь ударение.

Answer (score 5):

Если в окружающей местности (она же **округа**, ж. р.) не было, то ударение на втором слоге, а если в избирательном **округе** (голосующих в дачный сезон; м. р.), то на первом.